# Why can't I install pygame and livewires in python for the book 'Python Programming for the absolute beginner'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, livewires

In *Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner*, it requires you to download *pygame* and *livewires*. The book links you to a page where you can download a bundle of folders made for the book. In these folders are a setup wizard for *pygame* and a `.bat` file for *livewires*.

However, I ran the `pygame` wizard and when I use `import pygame` at the start of a Python script I get this nasty error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\pygam test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

When the launcher asked for when to put 'pygame' or something, I entered this:

```
C:\Python34
```

which seems about right to me. The `.bat` file for 'livewires' doesn't work at the moment either, but I guess that's because 'pygame' isn't working.

Sidenote: My `PATH` links to `C:\Python34` as well.

What is the problem?

Comment: you're using python3.

Comment: Yes i'm using python3?

Comment: AFAIK Livewires works best with Python 2.6.x .

Answer (score 2):

You're using Python3. Pygames install doesn't work well with python3. Use the tips here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/401342/how-to-download-pygame-in-python3-3.

Also, you won't be install the livewires module for much of the same reasons and the author gives a modified versions of liverwires, not the original thing. For this very reason I have rewritten livewires from the specs at the back of the book: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SuperWires

Comment: This is most strange! The book is designed for Python 3.

Comment: I downloaded superwires and ran the launcher thing. I went through it, selecting python 3.1.1 when it prompted and such. It then completed very quickly and when I went onto to python to try `from superwires import games` it gave me back the most obvious of errors, `no module named superwires` meaning it hasn't installed. However, in my \Python31\ folder there is the RemoveSuperWires.exe and the log thing so that happened? What went wrong? (Sorry I took so damn long to reply, its been like a month!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.delmarlearning.com/companions/content/1435455002/downloads/py3e_software.zip) is the download to go with *python programming for the absolute beginner* for pygame and python.